# Animation of rotating a border with a photo

Tags: html, css

I'd like the border to rotate on a circular DIV with the background photo

This is an icon in **maplibre-gl**

The code below rotates but:

- the position of the icon has changed to the top left corner of the browser (if I turn off the animation, the location is correct)
- the photo also rotates (it should stand still)

Code:

```
.userLocation {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-image: url('@Model.LogoPath');
    background-size: contain;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.borderAnimation {
    border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 20s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Safari 5 */
    -moz-animation: rotate 20s linear infinite; /* Firefox 5-15 */
    -o-animation: rotate 20s linear infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
    animation: rotate 20s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Safari 5 */
    border: 4px dashed #32A3F0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from {
        transform-origin: center center;
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {
        transform-origin: center center;
        transform: translateX(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update you post by pasting html and css, you can insert snippet into post by using `<>` icon or by clicking `CTRL + M`

Comment: What is translateX(360deg) trying to do? Also as @ulou has pointed out, we need to see your HTML structure to see why the photo is rotating.